# How to debug in the application.js with compressed javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got the following errors,

When I opened the Chrome javascript console,then look insight it.

`application.js?body=1:1249`

It is just  a group of compressed js code

And I've open the in the `development.rb`

```
  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

I can not grep the any piece of the javascript source code in my Rails app.

So I don't know where does it come from ?

How can I fix the unknown error quickly in Rails ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

```
Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found application.js?body=1:1249
GET http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=vbqxugf&userId=Ei9nuSYzM8NCWiFeoMKLn6&CTID=addtofeedly net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: you have to close other tabs except your project. Then you will not see that type of unwanted js files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure sure you are running rails in development mode and

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

is set in `development.rb`

If you do not manage to get the uncompressed version you the another option:

Compressed files can be made "pretty" in Chrome if you click on the `{}` symbol.
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pretty-print

[image: Before]

[image: After]